# How to remove post_content from being search in woo commerce wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce

My e-commerce is showing irrelevant information because is searching on content post of the products hence the search is not working effectively.I need help on how to remove search on content on woo commerce wordpress

Comment: Are you meaning content from the post type of `post`? If so, you can change this guide's code to `$wp_post_types['post']->exclude_from_search = true;` where appropriate. https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/how-to-exclude-pages-from-search-in-wordpress/

Comment: Is excluding the woo commerce product description from being searched when a user searches because it is giving wrong results.